# Why do we share parameters between two different inputs in the embeddings layer?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, word-embeddings, embeddings

I noticed in some deep learning networks that have two inputs to the network, they use one embeddings layer to share the parameters between these two different inputs.

As an example, in Keras:

```
input_target = Input((1,))
input_context = Input((1,))
embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, input_length=1, name='embedding')
target = embedding(input_target)
context = embedding(input_context)
```

Why do they use this way?

To make everything clear, the other case is: for each input we have different embeddings layer before moving to the RNN or CNN layers.

Comment: It depends on the use case. Sometimes you have parameter sharing in order to decrease parameters or because all inputs need to be embedded in the same manner.

Comment: @Andreas Look , could you give an example?

Comment: e.g. you embedd two images in a low dimensional space where distance is interpretable and want to calculate their similarity afterwards. like siamese networks